# Deleting duplicate records from tha Snowflake table without a PK

Tags: merge, duplicates, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a system where we load data into a staging table every night and then use the MERGE to upload it into the final table.
I discovered that there are duplicate records in the final table. My debugging revealed that the one of the fields that is used for the JOIN condition is NULL so the MERGE is inserting the records rather than updating it.

I need to delete the duplicate records and need to know how.

There is no Primary Key on this table just columns mapped to the flat files and then control columns

for ex:

| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | CREATED_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Doe | 18-JAN-2024 |
| Jane | Doe | 18-JAN-2024 |
| Phil | Knight | 18-JAN-2024 |
| John | Doe | 18-JAN-2024 |

How do I delete the last record which is a duplicate

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps the "replace the data" of which Himanshu INSERT OVERWRITE should work, and how to get the wanted to be kept rows.

the sub-select can be done with a QUALIFY which is the same as sub-select, but avoid the need to name columns. Thus use a CTE for test data only:

```
with data(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, CREATED_DATE) as (
select * from values
    ('John', 'Doe','18-JAN-2024'::date),
    ('Jane', 'Doe','18-JAN-2024'::date),
    ('Phil', 'Knight','18-JAN-2024'::date),
    ('John', 'Doe','18-JAN-2024'::date)
)
select *
from data
QUALIFY row_number()over(partition by first_name, last_name, created_date order by null) = 1;
```

gives:

| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | CREATED_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | Doe | 2024-01-18 |
| John | Doe | 2024-01-18 |
| Phil | Knight | 2024-01-18 |

but really, DISTINCT should be used really:

```
select distinct *
from data;
```

gives the same results.

So as you the replacement method, a setup:

```
create or replace table data_table(first_name string, last_name string, created_date date);
insert into data_table values
    ('John', 'Doe','18-JAN-2024'::date),
    ('Jane', 'Doe','18-JAN-2024'::date),
    ('Phil', 'Knight','18-JAN-2024'::date),
    ('John', 'Doe','18-JAN-2024'::date);
```

we can remove the duplicates with:

```
insert overwrite into data_table
select distinct *
from data_table;
```

[image]

Comment: I've always used to the QUALIFY method myself, but I've never really compared the 2 on performance for large tables.  Have you ever looked into that?  I'm sure cardinality and how much duplication there is probably affects things.

Comment: "we didn't insert duplicate data" was our working position, and the handful of times, it was prior to QUALIFY or INSERT OVERWRITE commands were added. We went the more CREATE, RENAME/SWAP style solution. But given we also used insert times, I do not recall ever having truly duplicate values, even if we had "duplicate data" which would blow out joins.

Comment: But to the question of performance, all is just guessing think/words: a duplicate on `*` should be a full row hash, which is most honest (and thus should be performant) than the row number which is having to bucket on the partition.. but there could be an optimalization for `row_number() =1` that keeps one row per partition hash, thus distribute almost as quickly as I think how the distinct should process.

Comment: Thanks for the response. One thing I failed to mention is that the Date field has a timestamp on it so distinct * might not return the unique record

Comment: Yip, those not mentioned things have impact. At which point the that should use ROW_NUMBER and order by the date, if you want to keep the oldest timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

one way you can delete duplicate is to use the analytical function row_number() over (partition... ) and select/ insert into a table where row_number() = 1.

--untested

```
insert overwrite into temp_table
with duplicate_table as(
       select dup_table.*,  row_number() 
    over (partition by FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME order by  CREATED_DATE) as r_num from dup_table)
   select FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME, CREATED_DATE from duplicate_table 
   where r_num = 1;
```

Comment: it can be cleaner to ether move the `ROW_NUMBER` into a QUALIFY clause, or if your uncomfortable with that, use the `EXCLUDE(r_num)` so you do not need to name that other columns of the base table.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment on Simeon's answer, you can tweak the `qualify` clause a little

```
create or replace yourtable as --or use insert overwrite into if you wish

select *
from yourtable 
qualify row_number()over(partition by first_name, last_name order by created_date asc) = 1;
```

;